# Is there any similar function in JasperReports like isblankwhennull?

Tags: jasper-reports

My issue is the when I use `isblankwhennull =true` ,it will replace all the fields with blank space.
I don't want blank space on the place of `null`. I want `"n/a"` or `"-"`. I have searched many related question and they have given the solution.

```
($F{address_street1}.equals(null) ? "" : $F{address_street1}+ " ")
```

But It seem that if I used this, I have to make change throughout my *JasperReports*'s report so that is not what I am looking for.

I want similar to `isblankwhennull` but it should replace null with `"-"` or what ever I want to set there.

Answer (score 3):

### #SOLUTION 1

You can modify query for that and get modified data before using it for jasper report,

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(Person.NAME,''), 'N/A')
```

In short just modify the data before setting it as datasource.

---

### #SOLUTION 2

You can add new static text with value `N/A` or `-` whatever you like, exactly on the main text field and set `isBlankWhenNull="true"` for the *main textfield* and use ***print when expression*** for *newly added static text*.

```
$F{name}==null
```

***FOR EXAMPLE***

```
      <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement key="" x="180" y="0" width="200" height="16"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement key="" x="180" y="0" width="200" height="16">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}==null]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <text><![CDATA[N/A]]></text>
        </staticText>
```

---

***NOTE***

But I thinks `$F{name}.equals(null) ? "-" :$F{name}` is better solution than second solution if fields are more.

Comment: Hey will you provide me example of second step.

Comment: 1 option seem to be good but with second option still, I have to make change in my jasper file.

Comment: `$F{name}.equals(null)` for me sounds like a waiting-to-happen null pointer exception, as `$F{name}` will resolve to null and then it will be invoked the `equals` method on that null object